# installation stack-auditor plugin in cloudfoundry cli

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I tried to install the stack-auditor plugin from https://github.com/cloudfoundry/stack-auditor. But I always get the follwoing error:

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:60499: socket: Ein ungültiges Argument wurde angegeben.
exit status 1
File is not a valid cf CLI plugin binary.
```

I have downloaded the windows plugin and I am using Windows 10 1709 and cf cli version 6.44.1+c3b20bfbe.2019-05-08

Comment: Have to ask. Did you unzip the plugin? When you run `cf install-plugin <file>`, `file` should point to the extracted file not the zip you download from Github. Aside from that, what is the sha256 hash of the file you downloaded? Maybe it got corrupted?

Comment: Yes I unzipped the plugin. How can I check the sha256 hash?

Comment: You can run `Get-FileHash <path-to-file> | Format-List` in Powershell, since you're on Windows. Mac/Linux can run `shasum -a 256 <path-to-file>`. For version 0.0.3, here's what I get for the zip -> `88a0098fc08b99d6438f178c830889aea72ac689a118fa184516fa4c83395c84`. Here's what I get for the extracted file `8422d65d470545bf8c641054497d31728bd799086a58596bbec2ae14ababfc4e`.

Comment: I get the same hash as you for the extracted file. I seems that this plugin does not work on windows. Now I have tried on Ubuntu Linux, there it works...

Comment: If you haven't done so already, please open a Github issue.